# ConstUnsafePointer swift

Tags: swift

How do I make a ConstUnsafePointer that points to a string? Something like

```
 let someString = "abcd\r\n"
 let buff: ConstUnsafePointer<UInt8>  = ???

 self.outputStream?.write(buffer:UnsafePointer<UInt8>, maxLength: <#Int#>)
```

So basicaly what I want isto to "convert" that "someString" to a type that after I can pass as a parameter to my outputStream?.write method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `UInt8` array from the string with

```
let buff = [UInt8](someString.utf8)
```

and then write the buffer to an output stream with

```
let written = outputStream.write(buff, maxLength: buff.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let someString = "abcd\r\n"
someString.withCString { (buff: ConstUnsafePointer<Int8>) in
  // do stuff with buff in here
}
```